# Is my Hamiltonian correct?

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, economics

To solve the following optimization problem,
$$
\max _{\left\{\ell_t\right\}} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} u\left(c_t, N_t\right) d t
$$
subject to
$$
\dot{N}_t  =\left(\bar{b}\ell_t-\delta\right) N_t, \\
c_t   =w_t\left(1-\ell_t\right) + \varphi \dot{N_t}-\tau_t,\\
$$
where $\ell_t,c_t$ are control variables and $N_t$ is state variable.

I combined the two budget constraints, that is,
$$
\dot{N}_t  = \frac{1}{1-\varphi}[w_t\left(1-\ell_t\right)+\left(\bar{b}\ell_t-\delta\right) N_t - c_t-\tau_t].
$$
Hence my current Hamiltonian is
$$
\mathcal{H}=u\left(c_t, N_t\right)+v_t \frac{1}{1-\varphi}[w_t\left(1-\ell_t\right)+\left(\bar{b}\ell_t-\delta\right) N_t - c_t-\tau_t].
$$
Is that correct?